# how to Add buttons or hyperlink on notification in Linux?

Tags: linux, notifications, web-crawler

I was wondering of creating a Linux-based application where the app crawls over the web for current news and show them as a notification but I want to also add the feature that if the news is very important then the user can mark it with a star or a button with "ok" symbol.

So my main focus is - is there a way by which I can modify the ubuntu notification.Please guide I think that would bring a revolution in ubuntu notification system.